# Ограничение listbox wpf только одним элементом

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listbox

Добрый день. Как можно ограничить листбокс одним элементом? Или же сделать так чтобы новый элемент появлялся вместо первого?

Comment: Можно узнать зачем вам такое поведение?

Comment: Это всё равно, что идти на рыбалку с ружьем вместо удочки. Листбокс предназначен именно для множества элементов.) Думаю есть более подходящий элемент управления для ваших целей.

Comment: В данной ситуации подходит только листбокс. Так как используется 'ObservableCollection<Downloading>'. Пытался сделать ка-то так: If( ListBox1.SelectedItems.Count = 3) {
    ListBox1.SelectedItems.Remove(ListBox1.SelectedItems(2))
} Но на коллекции стоит read only.

Comment: Просто не помещайте в связанную коллекцию больше одного элемента и всё. Т.е. вместо `myCollection.Add(....)` пишите `myCollection[0] = ...`